# dplyr: use environment variables in select_() and mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr

I made a function in which dplyr is used. I can select arguments using `get()` for `select_()`, but not for `mutate()`.

This is the code I used.

Create Test Data:

```
test <- tibble(Q1=c(NA,NA,NA,4,5),
       Q2=c(1,2,NA,NA,NA),
       Q3=c(NA,NA,3,NA,NA),
       Group=c("B", "B", "C", "A", "A"))
```

This returns error.

```
## Create y column
create_y <- function(x1, x2, x3, Group){
    length <- length(x1)
    res <- c()
    for (i in 1:length){
        if(Group[i]=="A")
            res <- c(res, x1[i])
        if(Group[i]=="B")
            res <- c(res, x2[i])
        if(Group[i]=="C")
            res <- c(res, x3[i])
    }
    return(res)
}

reg_figure <- function(var1, var2, var3){
    test %>% select_(.dots=c(get("var1"), get("var2"), get("var3"), "Group")) %>%
    mutate(y=create_y(as.name(get("var1")), as.name(get("var2")), as.name(get("var3")), Group))
}

reg_figure("Q1", "Q2", "Q3") # error
```

I want a result like this:

```
| Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Group | y |
|----|----|----|-------|---|
| NA | 1  | NA | B     | 1 |
| NA | 2  | NA | B     | 2 |
| NA | NA | 3  | C     | 3 |
| 4  | NA | NA | A     | 4 |
| 5  | NA | NA | A     | 5 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.[[get("var1")]]` to get a column of tibble as a vector.

```
reg_figure <- function(var1, var2, var3){
    test %>% select_(.dots=c(get("var1"), get("var2"), get("var3"), "Group")) %>%
    mutate(y=create_y(.[[get("var1")]], .[[get("var2")]], .[[get("var3")]], Group))
}
reg_figure("Q1", "Q2", "Q3")
```